# Random messages in logchat android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Even without launching the app on the emulator/phone, new messages appear
Maybe its normal? Logging from Other Apps: It is possible that other apps on your device are generating logs and those logs are appearing in the logchat of Android Studio.
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Universy"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.universy.UniversityDetails" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr4Xm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVAYE.png)

I have no idea what else to put in here.
I don't know what to do about it

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the logcat to show only messages from your app. Logcat will show all messages logged from all apps, including system apps and this can be a ton of messages.

Comment: If its normal. Thank you